# Learn Calculus with applications instead of rigor

Tags: calculus, applications

**OBJECTIVE:** I am looking for some resources/books to learn Calculus. I have searched archives here and noticed that recommended books from reputed authors Spivak, Courant, Hardy, Apostol are based on rigor.  I do not want rigor, proofs, theorems and analysis. I want practical side of Calculus. Of course this does not mean I don't like theory, I do want to learn fundamentals of Calculus, I just don't want to be bogged down into too much of details (the way school taught me to hate Math)

**BACKGROUND:** My field of work is Data Science and Machine-Learning and I need a good grasp of Statistics and Probability, but every book I pick up on these subjects talks in weird inverted-italicised-9  and elongated-corneres-trimmed-S symbols (differential and integral symbols respectively). I have worked through colege algebra from [edX MOOC with Arizona State University](https://www.edx.org/course/college-algebra-problem-solving-asux-mat117x)) and  Pre-Calculus from http://www.coolmath.com/ and currently studying [Calculus for the Ambitious](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/).

Any recources ?

Comment: Without rigor would be possible, but not without $\partial$ and $\int$.

Comment: @md2perpe I think my post gave out the meaning not intended, hence I have have edited it.

Comment: James Stewart is a very standard source for beginning calculus.  It is not fully rigorous.  However, you're of course going to have to learn the meaning of $\int, \Sigma, \partial$...

Comment: Have you looked at _Schaum's Outline of Calculus_ and _Schaum's 3,000 Solved Problems in Calculus_?

Comment: @Somos Just checked them out, they look good. Outlin eof Calculus is too damn expensive in India.  3000 solved problems's price is ok  (1988 edition)

Comment: @JairTaylor -- I started with Calculus Made Easy. Book is extremely clear on basic ideas of Calculus.